# Submit form when dropdownbox changes - not doing anything

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have created a view which contains a DropDownList to show or hide a set of records. The form works fine when I manually click the submit button but when I add the jQuery to automatically submit the form when the value of the DropDownList changes, it doesn't do anything.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Features", FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "filterForm" }))
{
  <label>Hide done:&nbsp;</label>
  @Html.DropDownList("HideDone", new List<SelectListItem>
  {
    new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "No" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "Yes" }
  }, new { @id = "HideDone" })
  <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#HideDone').on('change', function () {
    $('#filterForm').submit();
  });
});
```

If I view the source of the page, the form does have the id of `filterForm` and the DropDownLost has the id of `HideDone`.

I have tried moving the script inside the `Using {}` in case it made any difference but it did not.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors when you fire the `change` event on the `select`?

Comment: You should never submit a form on the `.change()` event of a `<select>` If the user uses the arrow keys to navigate the options it will be submitted immediately. (and note that you do not need `new { @id = "HideDone" }` - that `id` attribute is already added by the `DropDownList()` method)

Comment: Console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I added the id to make sure it was there!

Comment: is your `change` event of drop down getting called?

Comment: did you try alert in your onchange event?

Comment: I put an alert and it didn't appear. It suggests the change method isn't firing or isn't being detected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

As the script is in the View and the JQuery bundle is loaded in the _layout file, the JQuery bundle is being loaded AFTER the script above, meaning it won't work.

I need to move the JQuery bundle to load earlier in the _Layout file so it appears BEFORE the script above.

Answer (score 0):

```
or 
$("body").on("change", "#HideDone", function (e) {
 $('#filterForm').submit();
});
```

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). But on the other hand the delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. Basically this mean that only the container has been given the instruction; it is responsible for noticing events on behalf of its child elements. I've used a general container "body" just to be sure that exists.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.